# Property 'type' is missing in type 'AsyncThunkAction<fetchUserResponse, void, {}>' but required in type 'AnyAction'

Tags: typescript, redux-toolkit

Code:

```
import { configureStore, ConfigureStoreOptions, createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import logger from 'redux-logger';

interface fetchUserResponse {
  name: string;
}

const fetchUser = createAsyncThunk<fetchUserResponse, void>('users/fetchUser', async () => {
  return { name: 'teresa teng' };
});

const usersSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'users',
  initialState: { name: '' },
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(fetchUser.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.name = action.payload.name;
    });
  },
});

interface UserState {
  name: string;
}

interface AppState {
  user: UserState;
}

const storeConfig: ConfigureStoreOptions<AppState> = {
  reducer: {
    user: usersSlice.reducer,
  },
};

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  storeConfig.middleware = (getDefaultMiddlewares) => getDefaultMiddlewares().concat(logger);
}

const store = configureStore(storeConfig);

store.dispatch(fetchUser()); // TSC throws error
```

TSC throws the below error when I try to dispatch `fetchUser()` action.

> Argument of type 'AsyncThunkAction<fetchUserResponse, void, {}>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction'.
> Property 'type' is missing in type 'AsyncThunkAction<fetchUserResponse, void, {}>' but required in type 'AnyAction'.ts(2345)

What generic parameters need to be passed to generic type `ConfigureStoreOptions` so I can pass the TSC type check.

package versions:

```json
"@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.5.0",
"typescript": "^4.1.2"
```

**UPDATE**

If I don't use `ConfigureStoreOptions`, I will get the below error when I try to set the `middleware` property for `storeConfig` dynamicly.

> Property 'middleware' does not exist on type '{ reducer: { user: Reducer<{ name: string; }, AnyAction>; }; }'.ts(2339)

Answer (score 2):

redux-toolkit maintainer here

`ConfigureStoreOptions` is *really* not a type that you should ever use by hand - it's meant to be inferred by actually calling `configureStore`. (I really wouldn't know how to type that by hand and I've done most of the work on the current RTK types)

This is actually the first time I've ever seen anyone do this. Is there some pressing reason that you really really have to do this? Maybe I can offer an alternative.

Having seen your updated code I'd really suggest you just do something like

```
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    user: usersSlice.reducer,
  },
  middleware(getDefaultMiddlewares) {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
      return getDefaultMiddlewares().concat(logger);
    }
    else {
      return getDefaultMiddlewares()
    }
  }
});
```

You can see it working in [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgYwgOwGbAOYFcoCmAyjNAQDRwDC6WehJZA8mDMOgM6XKECGMBAIIcAnmmQAVABa40Aa258BRADbBkBOAF84GKBBBwA5AAFCAE1wAPAFYcA9KQgq5wGEYDcAKFCRYxkxgRMAIHNAhzAiMfcGh4FQhsbAIoXX1DIwtrAFoEpJTPLx80ASgMXg1dAhhkKQBVDhSAJVDINEbELzg4NF4QAgAuOA4YKGA0bG8tItR2+Axq2oaUuABeFCUhUXFpWTkAHgWa+saoFo42xsoANwhgcwA+AAojXFOHI6XTo0pebeQ4E8AJRrB6dbqEGD4NCIHp9QbGUqhXhwAQTIzaKZA7xeWYjOBvFIcVTqTTrHgEfjENQaJ4ILpw-pDV7vH4M8ZuYC8FQkKlDJC9JnGDFacgMrIaKAcfmihkEKyjXgtSyS6WAgBGuGAKkiUBBqzB9O63U12t1ADpeOZzFQ-gQnp8TilzRhcCosCoVARzJQniMqb9kGx0PrDQzjcMYFTzYKyXAKsG0OawLwRAkrTH4d4I1psQzZbmceNSuVKssoLyBODGQiRmMJlMisWUqXNIIwGBK5ojQTTkNy13GzNOPARmQ1ihaDh8MRSIQ6eLvbhJfzw72UkNCVKSRpzRKUmLurLuiB7uYvQB3Xjz5IwAAiBHKbpgAFkz5fr6EQT3usAMICwH0DQOA4c0CDQa5zQAOSYO8AFEAH04KggA1OAAEJVnWIxAIiZdEyMb81whapoTgW8HyfFRX3fAgr0IDhgXNWZkH4J48mSPVs2NaYIwIFQOh-Y1ITIijH14Z832tD8GOBNdeO0LxCyKMdCHNcxgAufhagdRYnSgYEgSAA)

Comment: I added more context to explain why I have to use `ConfigureStoreOptions` interface.

Comment: Still got same TS type error when execute `store.dispatch(fetchUser())` statement

Comment: I linked a playground above where that code is working. Are you doing something different?

Comment: It's weird. I created a minimal, reproducible example here: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-v26-codelab/blob/main/issues/rtk-dispatch-ts-type/index.ts

Comment: just looked at your example. You have to move `storeConfig` into the `configureStore` call. It should not be declared externally.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231204/discussion-between-slideshowp2-and-phry).

Answer (score 2):

As @phry said, you can skip the usage of the `ConfigureStoreOptions` type entirely if you just call `configureStore` directly:

```
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    user: usersSlice.reducer
  }
});
```

---

The piece that's missing from your `storeConfig: ConfigureStoreOptions<AppState>` type is the declaration of the middleware type.  The current type does not include thunk or any other middleware, so you cannot dispatch an `AsyncThunkAction`.  You would need to adjust your `storeConfig` type to support thunks.  You do this by setting the third generic type parameter `M`.

Here is how the type is defined:

```
ConfigureStoreOptions<S = any, A extends Action<any> = AnyAction, M extends Middlewares<S> = Middlewares<S>>
```

You need to import the `ThunkMiddleware` type directly from "redux-thunk" because "@reduxjs/toolkit" does not re-export it.

```
import { configureStore, ConfigureStoreOptions } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import {ThunkMiddleware} from "redux-thunk";

const storeConfig: ConfigureStoreOptions<AppState, AnyAction, [ThunkMiddleware<AppState, AnyAction>]> = {
  reducer: {
    user: usersSlice.reducer
  }
};

const store = configureStore(storeConfig);

store.dispatch(fetchUser());
```

You can do this and it works, but it's honestly silly when you could just pass your options directly to `configureStore` and get all of the types inferred.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue and I had to add `middleware: [thunk as ThunkMiddleware]` to my configureStore() to get the correct types for createAsyncThunk()

Comment: In order to use `redux-persist` I needed to explicitly include the `redux-thunk` middleware in my store config. After doing so I was getting the "property 'type' is missing" errors mentioned in this question.

For me, writing the middleware config as `middleware: [thunk] as [ThunkMiddleware]` is what worked.